# Aes encryption is giving different results PHP?

Tags: php, encryption

I am trying to decode a hexadecimal string and encrypt it using aes algorithm .But it is giving different result when passed through the same algorithm in java. But passing the data through hex2bin() and printing its output and then using it as data gives the right result.Why ?

This is snippet of php code that i am using ::

```
<?php

$data = hex2str("ce4f5bf05a57b6f9e0d7df628d266d66");
//$data = pack('H*', "ce4f5bf05a57b6f9e0d7df628d266d66");
echo "data:".$data."  length:".strlen($data).PHP_EOL;
$data2 = "?O[?ZW?????b?&mf";
echo "data2:".$data2."  length:".strlen($data2).PHP_EOL;

if (strcmp($data,$data2)) {
    echo "Both are equal".PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo "Both are unequal".PHP_EOL;
}


$key = 'mysaltmysalt1234';
$blocksize = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, 'ecb');
$data = pkcs5_pad($data, $blocksize);
$data2 = pkcs5_pad($data2, $blocksize);
echo "type data -- " . gettype($data).PHP_EOL;
echo "type data 2 -- ". gettype($data2).PHP_EOL;
echo "encoding data --" . mb_detect_encoding($data).PHP_EOL;
echo "encoding data 2 -- ". mb_detect_encoding($data2).PHP_EOL;
echo "data:".$data."  length:".strlen($data).PHP_EOL;
echo "data2:".$data2."  length:".strlen($data2).PHP_EOL;
echo "encrypted data : ".base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB)).PHP_EOL;
echo "encrypted data2 : ".base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data2, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB)).PHP_EOL;
die;

function pkcs5_pad($text, $blocksize) {
    $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize);
    return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
} 

function hex2str($hex) {
    $str = '';
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($hex);$i+=2) $str .= chr(hexdec(substr($hex,$i,2)));
    return $str;
}
```

Output -- >

```
data:?O[?ZW?????b?&mf  length:16
data2:?O[?ZW?????b?&mf  length:16
Both are equal
type data -- string
type data 2 -- string
encoding data --UTF-8
encoding data 2 -- UTF-8
data:?O[?ZW?????b?&mf  length:32
data2:?O[?ZW?????b?&mf  length:32
encrypted data : SWDBVA282EY9qXkpe4vuFz+prMZrefR6nymIB3KQpf0=
encrypted data2 : STICb3fdCrutwEy6cg5/sD+prMZrefR6nymIB3KQpf0=
```

Java code --

```
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.security.MessageDigest;

public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String keyhex,salt,salto,keystr;
    salt = "mysaltmysalt1234";
    keyhex = "ce4f5bf05a57b6f9e0d7df628d266d66";
    byte[] binkey = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(keyhex);
    keystr = new String(binkey);
    salto = encrypt(salt.getBytes(), keystr);
    System.out.println(salto);
  }



  public static String encrypt(byte[] key,String inputString) {
    try
    {
      SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key,
 "AES");
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
      cipher.init(1, secretKeySpec);
      byte[] aBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputString.getBytes());
      String base64 = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(aBytes));
      return base64; 
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception occured in encrypt : "+ex.toString());
    }
    return null; 
  }

}
```

Java code output : STICb3fdCrutwEy6cg5/sD+prMZrefR6nymIB3KQpf0=

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it has been abandonware for nearly a decade now. It has therefore been deprecated and will be removed from the core and into PECL in PHP 7.2. It does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution, are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: Do not use ECB mode, it is insecure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

Instead use CBC mode with a random IV, just prefix the encrypted data with the IV for use in decryption, it does not need to not secret.